# ActiveRecord - How are Associations stored/generated? Need to import XML to Postgres database in Sinatra App

Tags: ruby, xml, postgresql, activerecord, sinatra

I have an XML dataset I am trying to import into a Postgresql database to be used by a Sinatra app.

The data consists, essentially, of:

```
ArchiveObjects
Tags
```

I would like to define these relationships in my DB Migration:

```
ArchiveObject - has_many Tags
ArchiveObject - has_many_and_belongs_to ArchiveObjects
Tag - belongs_to ArchiveObject
```

We can manipulate the XML and were thinking it is best to treat this relationship as an array of ID's, for example:

```
ArchiveObject.tags = [Array, of, Tags]
```

However, I'm unsure how we should format the XML, am I correct in assuming that the migration `has_many :Tags` creates a column to hold an array? Or does ActiveRecord do something completely different? (eg: Create a junction table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_many :tags` will imply that the database schema will look as follows

```
create table archive_object(
   id int not null
);

create table tag(
   id int not null,
   archive_object_id int not null
);
```

i.e. each tag record will contain the id of the archive object that it belongs to.

So there is a column involved, but it doesn't contain an array struct, it contains a reference to another table, and it is the Owned object that contains a reference to its parent.

Edit:  An attempt to further explain this.

Given the structures:

```
A1 : ArchiveObject, A1.tags => [T1, T2, T3]
A2 : ArchiveObject, A2.tags => [T4, T5]
```

You would have the SQL tables:

```
archive_objects
id | name
-------------
 1 | A1
 2 | A2

tags
id | archive_object_id | name
-----------------------------
 1 |                 1 | T1
 2 |                 1 | T2
 3 |                 1 | T3
 4 |                 2 | T4
 5 |                 2 | T5
```

This is the whole point behind a relational database model - the logical list of [T1,T2,T3] belonging to A1 is mapped as a table with 3 rows, linked in a SQL join:

```
A1.tags # would run the query SELECT * FROM tags WHERE archive_object_id = 1;
A2.tags # would run the query SELECT * FROM tags WHERE archive_object_id = 2;
```

and is part of the heavy lifting that ActiveRecord endeavours to do for you.

Edit 2: demonstration of how to create and save an ArchiveObject

```
class ArchiveObject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :archive_object
end

# create a structure
ao = ArchiveObject.new({
        :name=>'A1',
        :p1=>'some param',
        :p2=>'some other param'})

t1 = Tag.new({
         :name=>'T1',
         :somevalue=>'S1',
         :someothervalue=>'S2'})
t2 = Tag.new({
         :name=>'T2',
         :somevalue=>'S3',
         :someothervalue=>'S4'})

ao.tags = [t1, t2]
ao.save

# at this point you have a record in archive_objects and two records in tags
```

Any fields you want present in either ArchiveObject or Tags you would generate through a migration.

Comment: How does the `tag.archive_object_id` handle having multiples, for example, if the `archive_object` has multiple tags associated with it? It won't be an array?

Comment: There will be multiple Tag records in the tag table, each linked to the same ArchiveObject.  See above

Comment: activerecord also provides accessors to get and set arrays of ids on the `has_many` side. so `A1.tag_ids` and `A1.tag_ids = [1,2,3]`

Comment: I see, thank you for the upate, very informative. Thus, this migration is, in essence, simply creating a Junction table then, correct? Then I'm wondering how I should import my XML data - since I can't just import it into 'ArchiveObjects.tags' as an array, I would need to import these relationships directly into the Junction Table then? Would this table also really be called 'Tags'? Wouldn't that interfere with the Tags themselves (which has titles and other data?)

Comment: Your titles and other data would also be part of the tags table - the tables above are for illustrative purposes only.  Updated again above to show creation.

Comment: Very helpful thank you – I'm sorry if this is an incredibly dense last question, so after `ao.tags = [t1, t2]` and `ao.save`, the tag table will also have two more rows with `archive_object_id` and I assume, the ID of the tag?

Comment: @mcfinnigan I'm terribly sorry, one last question :) I suppose this is more the issue - as we are importing this data from XML, how could we generate these tag objects without creating many duplicates? Or would it be a matter of 1. Creating the archive_object, 2. Check if tag exists (via a search for the 'name'), if not, create it. 3. Associate the tag object. I suppose my main question is about doing all this association when the primary keys aren't available before the data is imported.

Comment: @waffl rather than searching the list of tags by name, just add them to a hash keyed by name as you create them and don't create a new tag if tags[name] != nil, then at the end you could just call `archive_object.tags = tags.values` followed by `save`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52772/discussion-between-waffl-and-mcfinnigan)